# Type Mismatch with Variant / Integer

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get this sheet in working order for my work and following this video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahYoy5L3ec.

I have followed the formula exact and tried some basic troubleshooting but my knowledge and use of VBA is basic at best.

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

I have an example of the code which is causing me a problem below:

(I managed to get to the section of code where I am supposed to be creating the All Pages access for users)

The error seems to be highlighted in the debugger for this line:

`If Target.Value = Empty Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "Ð"`
window watch says it is a variant/integer

````
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I4:Q8")) Is Nothing Then```

    If Target.Value = "Ð" Then
        Target.Value = "Ï"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Target.Value = "x" Then Target.Value = "Ð"
    If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Target.Value = "x"
    If Target.Value = Empty Then Target.Value = "Ð"

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H4:H8")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Ð" Then
        Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "Ï"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Value = "x" Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
    If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "x"
    If Target.Value = Empty Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
End If

End Sub
````

Comment: Why are you using ^ in place of & ?

Comment: Well that was easy.... Solved! Thanks for the proof read!

Comment: Used like this, `^` is the exponent operator. Because the exponent operator expects numeric operands, and `":Q"` cannot be implicitly coerced into a numeric value, VBA throws a *type mismatch* error to let you know that it has no idea what to do with this instruction.

Answer (score 1):

#### Typo error

The error is due to the use of the symbol `^` instead of `&`.

Change these lines:

```
If Target.Value = "x" Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "x"
If Target.Value = Empty Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" ^ Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
```

With these ones:

```
If Target.Value = "x" Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" & Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" & Target.Row).Value = "x"
If Target.Value = Empty Then Range("H" & Target.Row & ":Q" & Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
```

And it will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It did very much. I am now stuck on a much further part of the code.

Run-time error '424':  Object required. 

Not sure what range it is out on. Debugger says it is highlighted line: 

`For SheetCol = 10 To 18
SheetNm = .Cells(3, SheetCol).Value 'Sheet Name
If .Cells(UserRow.SheetCol).Value = "Ð" Then
    Sheets(SheetNm).Unprotect "123"
    Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If`

Any help on the above would be great?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. If you've another code issue, please open a new question and the community will help you. :)